# Python re.sub replaces everything instead of one group

Tags: python, regex

So. I have a string and need to replace every `;` surrounded by `"` to `,`
(In example `;` is in `"CANDIES,CHOC,DK,NFS (45-59% CACAO SOL 90%**!!!;!!!** 60-69% CACAO SOL"`)

**Code**

```
import re
a = '19905;"CANDIES,CHOC,DK,NFS (45-59% CACAO SOL 90%; 60-69% CACAO SOL";1;550;5,09;32,2;1,74;59,97;7,2;46,14;57;8,13;152;214;568;23;2,11;1,076;1,44;3,5;0;0,026;0,051;0,747;0,304;0,041;0;0;0;0;27,6;0,23;49;2;0;7;25;1;0;31;0,55;0;0;8;18,993;9,801;1,107;7;28,35;1 oz;127;1 bar;0'
print(re.sub('"[^"]*(;)[^"]*"', ',', a))
```

The only problem is that it outputs

```
19905;,;1;550;5,09;32,2;1,74;59,97;7,2;46,14;57;8,13;152;214;568;23;2,11;1,076;1,44;3,5;0;0,026;0,051;0,747;0,304;0,041;0;0;0;0;27,6;0,23;49;2;0;7;25;1;0;31;0,55;0;0;8;18,993;9,801;1,107;7;28,35;1 oz;127;1 bar;0
```

Instead of

```
19905;"CANDIES,CHOC,DK,NFS (45-59% CACAO SOL 90%, 60-69% CACAO SOL";1;550;5,09;32,2;1,74;59,97;7,2;46,14;57;8,13;152;214;568;23;2,11;1,076;1,44;3,5;0;0,026;0,051;0,747;0,304;0,041;0;0;0;0;27,6;0,23;49;2;0;7;25;1;0;31;0,55;0;0;8;18,993;9,801;1,107;7;28,35;1 oz;127;1 bar;0
```

Somewhy it replaces entire matched part

```
"CANDIES,CHOC,DK,NFS (45-59% CACAO SOL 90%, 60-69% CACAO SOL" --> ,
```

Comment: Use `re.sub('("[^"]*);([^"]*")', r'\1,\2', a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a single `;` to replace inside `"..."` you may fix your approach using

```
import re
a = '19905;"CANDIES,CHOC,DK,NFS (45-59% CACAO SOL 90%; 60-69% CACAO SOL";1;550;5,09;32,2;1,74;59,97;7,2;46,14;57;8,13;152;214;568;23;2,11;1,076;1,44;3,5;0;0,026;0,051;0,747;0,304;0,041;0;0;0;0;27,6;0,23;49;2;0;7;25;1;0;31;0,55;0;0;8;18,993;9,801;1,107;7;28,35;1 oz;127;1 bar;0'
print(re.sub('("[^"]*);([^"]*")', r'\1,\2', a))
# => 19905;"CANDIES,CHOC,DK,NFS (45-59% CACAO SOL 90%, 60-69% CACAO SOL";1;550;5,09;32,2;1,74;59,97;7,2;46,14;57;8,13;152;214;568;23;2,11;1,076;1,44;3,5;0;0,026;0,051;0,747;0,304;0,041;0;0;0;0;27,6;0,23;49;2;0;7;25;1;0;31;0,55;0;0;8;18,993;9,801;1,107;7;28,35;1 oz;127;1 bar;0
```

where `(...)` are placed around the parts you need to keep and then placeholders `\1` and `\2` are used in the replacement.

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/eLiFPY).

Else, use

```
import re
a = '19905;"CANDIES,CHOC,DK,NFS (45-59% CACAO SOL 90%; 60-69% CACAO SOL";1;550;5,09;32,2;1,74;59,97;7,2;46,14;57;8,13;152;214;568;23;2,11;1,076;1,44;3,5;0;0,026;0,051;0,747;0,304;0,041;0;0;0;0;27,6;0,23;49;2;0;7;25;1;0;31;0,55;0;0;8;18,993;9,801;1,107;7;28,35;1 oz;127;1 bar;0'
print(re.sub('"[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group().replace(';', ','), a))
```

to replace all `;` inside double quoted substrings with commas. See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/j8STkn).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
import regex as re     
print(re.sub(r'(?<="[^"]*);(?=[^"]*")',',',a))
```

May I also say, `"[^"]*(;)[^"]*"` in your regex matches all string inside double quotes and replaces it with '`,`', so such output resulted.